# Issues Downloading Data From GCP

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I'm following the tutorial here:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/professional-services/tree/master/machine-learning/solutions/energy_price_forecasting

There is a line that says to run the following:

```
Run: python -m data_preparation.data_prep to generate training/validation/testing data as well as to generate constants needed for normalization. The produced data has the following columns:
```

However, I keep getting the following error. Any idea on what I'm doing wrong.

Here is the error:

```
Abrahams-MBP:energy_forecasting abrahammathew$ python -m data_preparation.data_prep
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/abrahammathew/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/Users/abrahammathew/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/Users/abrahammathew/Desktop/energy_forecasting/data_preparation/data_prep.py", line 323, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/abrahammathew/Desktop/energy_forecasting/data_preparation/data_prep.py", line 317, in main
    client = bigquery.Client()
  File "/Users/abrahammathew/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/client.py", line 124, in __init__
    project=project, credentials=credentials, _http=_http)
  File "/Users/abrahammathew/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/client.py", line 215, in __init__
    _ClientProjectMixin.__init__(self, project=project)
  File "/Users/abrahammathew/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/client.py", line 169, in __init__
    project = self._determine_default(project)
  File "/Users/abrahammathew/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/client.py", line 182, in _determine_default
    return _determine_default_project(project)
  File "/Users/abrahammathew/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/cloud/_helpers.py", line 179, in _determine_default_project
    _, project = google.auth.default()
  File "/Users/abrahammathew/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/auth/_default.py", line 306, in default
    raise exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError(_HELP_MESSAGE)
google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError: Could not automatically determine credentials. Please set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS or explicitly create credentials and re-run the application. For more information, please see https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials.
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you have to configure the credentials for your GCP account first. In the same session of the command line [set environment variable](https://superuser.com/questions/79612/setting-and-getting-windows-environment-variables-from-the-command-prompt):

```
set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=<...>
```

You can set it on your machine in all commandline sessions in the local/machine environment variables tab (similarly to where you set your %PATH%).

The details on how to obtain JSON file with your credentials is given under [the URL that the exception points to](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#obtaining_and_providing_service_account_credentials_manually).

Comment: how would I find the .json file to associate the credentials with

Comment: did that and get this error now: "google.api_core.exceptions.Forbidden: 403 POST https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/energy-forecasting-211800/jobs: Access Denied: Dataset energy-forecasting-211800:Energy: The user energy-forecasting@energy-forecasting-211800.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have bigquery.tables.create permission for dataset energy-forecasting-211800:Energy."

Comment: Well, do you have permissions to this table?
Also, this seems like a separate issue. Could you please accept the answer for your initial question?

Comment: @ATMA you have to give the service account 'energy-forecasting@energy-forecasting-211800.iam.gserviceaccount.com' [bigquery.tables.create permission](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control#permissions) or [roles/bigquery.dataEditor](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control#roles) role. [Here](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-roles-to-service-accounts) you have the documention how to do it.